# Detecting UWP app's dismissed notifications in background task

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I need to take certain actions when my app's notifications are dismissed.

I'm using the stuff around [ToastNotificationHistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory) to retrieve / react to notification updates.

Following the docs, I'm registering a background task for the updates:

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "ToastHistoryChangedBackgroundTask";
builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger());
builder.Register();
```

Updates will come via `OnBackgroundActivated()`, along with some args in a `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail` (e.g., dismiss reason). However, this doesn't actually tell you *which* notifications have been updated. I manually keep track of the current state with `ToastNotificationManager.History.GetHistory()`; on updates I can check the difference and reason which notifications were removed.

This works fine, but when the app is not running, I miss removals. The background task fires even when the app is closed, so I do actually get the updates, but at that point in `OnBackgroundActivated()` the notifications are already gone. If, say, everything was cleared, `GetHistory()` will report 0 notifications but I have no previous state to compare to.

I've also tried the similar pattern using [UserNotificationChangedTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener); while it's a bit more general (listening to *all* notifications, not just the app's), it suffers from the same issue of getting the update after the notification no longer shows up in the query. Also note how the docs employ the same syncing mechanism to infer the delta.

Is there a way to retrieve the actual contents of the notification update, or perhaps another mechanism that would work around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the toast notification's `Dismissed` event from the background task? (You'll have to take a task deferral so you can keep running.)

Comment: @RaymondChen : I see your point, but which notification would I even subscribe to? At that point, as per my example, there would be 0 notifications reported.

Unless you're talking about out-of-process background tasks, but as I understand it those are deprecated right?

Comment: Out-of-process background tasks are still fully-supported. But if you don't like them, you could do this from a foreground process background task, too.

Comment: @IosifSpulber could you kindly share your solution with us?